# Page layout, CSS

Tags: html, css, facelets

I would like next to my dataGrid to have another table, floating left to it. Like this, located in the main div:

```
|     |      |
|  A  |   B  |
|     |      |
```

, where A is the current dataGrid, containing all user and B will be the new content. I tried with creating a table inside the main div and putting left and right part in 2 columns inside a row, but B go out of the field of main div. I tried putting CSS for left and right col and adding two extra div but it still does not look in this way. B goes below A. Please, give me an advice how can this be done. Here is the source of the page.

The code of my page is this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <div id="container" style="min-height: 100%; position: relative;">
            <div id="left"
                style="background-image: url('#{resource['images/left.png']}'); background-repeat: repeat-y; height: 1800px; width: 163px; float: left;">
                <br />
            </div>
            <div id="main" style="width: 920px; float: left;">
                <f:view>

                    <h:form rendered="#{not empty loginBean.name}">

                        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="css.css" />
                        <center>
                            <h2>My Profile</h2>
                        </center>

                        <p:dataGrid var="user" value="#{profileBean.userList}">
                            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    <p:graphicImage value="#{profileBean.image}" alt="${user.name}"
                                        width="150px" height="150px">

                                        <f:param name="userId" value="#{user.id}" />
                                    </p:graphicImage>
                                </f:facet>

                                <h:outputText value="Name: " />
                                <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" />

                                <h:outputText value="Phone: " />
                                <h:inputText value="#{user.phone}" required="true">
                                    <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]+" />
                                </h:inputText>


                                <h:outputText value="Role: " />
                                <h:outputText value="#{user.userRole.roleName}">
                                </h:outputText>

                                <f:facet name="footer">
                                    <h:panelGroup style="display:block; text-align:center">
                                        <p:commandButton id="submit" value="Save changes"
                                            actionListener="#{profileBean.editUser()}" >

                                <f:attribute name="profileBean.selectedUser" value="#{user}" />
                                            </p:commandButton>
                                    </h:panelGroup>
                                </f:facet>


                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:dataGrid>
                        <hr />
                    </h:form>
                </f:view>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="right"
            style="background-image: url('#{resource['images/right.png']}'); background-repeat: repeat-y; height: 1800px; width: 150px; float: right;">
            <br />
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be using `display:table` and `display:table-cell` will help you

here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7swu8cfe/)

**Mark UP**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display:table;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.left {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
.right {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:Blue;
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of "right" and "left" to fit in the width of the screen. You can do this by setting the divs width percentage wise. 
e.g width=25%

Comment: Still i is not located as it should be... The B part goes out of the main div, even if i put <div id ="rightPart"> inside <div id="main"..> and give leftPart and rightPart width.

Comment: Did you set the main div's width to 100%? 
In your code sample it is set to a fixed 920px, so the B will go out of it if width of A+B > 920px.